# how to insert a tr which is deleted from another table using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know how to remove a tr from the table1 on click of delete. But i want to insert it in to another table .

How to do that?

here is the code i used to remove the tr.

```
<script languge="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.delete').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //Getting the TR to remove it in case of successful deletion
  var objRow = $(this).closest('tr');

  $.ajax({ 
   type: 'post',
   url: "<?= site_url('test/fndelete') ?>/",
   data: {"id":$(this).prev().text()},
   success: function(results) {
     if (results == "") { 
      objRow.remove();     
     } else {

    alert("Error!");
     }
   }  
  });
  return false;
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i didnt test it but i think this will work:

```
success: function(results) { 
    if (results == "") {
        $('#table_where_all_the_deleted_stuff_goes').append('<tr>' + objRow.html() + '</tr>');
        objRow.remove();
    } else { 
        alert("Error!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: There are much more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: 'post',
   url: "<?= site_url('test/fndelete') ?>/",
   data: {"id":$(this).prev().text()},
   success: function(results) {
     if (results == "") { 
         objRow.appendTo('#new_table tbody');
     } else {
         alert("Error!");
     }
   }  
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify this already great answer, appending an DOM element to a new container will also remove it from the old container at the same time. So there is no need to call the extra `remove` function and is why it is missing from this answer.